# Selenium Hover Over - Element located in the JavaScript

Tags: selenium

Using Selenium-Java, on Amazon.com (url:www.amazon.com) webpage, I would like to start with hover-over "Departments", following "Departments" > "Books & Audible" > "Books", I would like to land on "Books at Amazon" webpage.

The difficulty: "Books & Audible" is hidden in the javascript and I donot know how to access this by "Find By".

Your help to get a working Selenese code is greatly appreciated.

Comment: What have you tried and what was the result? This is not a code for hire site. You need to do some research and provide the code you have tried and we can help you if you run into errors.

Answer (score 0):

How is it hidden? Can you please provide your HTML code here?

Regarding performing a mouse hover over, below is a code snippet you can use as reference:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.action_chains import ActionChains

firefox = webdriver.Firefox()
firefox.get('url')
element_to_hover_over = firefox.find_element_by_id("id")

hover = ActionChains(firefox).move_to_element(element_to_hover_over)
hover.perform()
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: Appreciate your valued response.  As I mentioned please visit: [link](http://www.amazon.com) and follow the steps highlighted in my original question and you can view "Page Source" for html code.